# Sort by date descending comparator not working as expected

Tags: java, sorting, comparator

Trying to make sense of the following output:

```
public class CommunicationComparator implements Comparator<Communication> {
    @Override
    public int compare(Communication comm1, Communication comm2) {
        long t1 = comm1.getDate().getTime();
        long t2 = comm2.getDate().getTime();
        return (int) (t2 - t1);
    }
}
```

The method getDate() returns a java.sql.Timestamp.

Here is the output before the sort:

```
for (Communication n : retVal) {
    System.out.println(n.getDate().toString());
}
```

> 2012-10-03 10:02:02.0
>   2012-10-07 03:02:01.0
>   2012-10-08 13:02:02.0
>   2012-10-09 03:02:00.0
>   2012-11-26 10:02:05.0
>   2012-11-28 11:28:11.0
>   2012-12-03 12:03:01.0
>   2012-12-06 15:03:01.0
>   2012-12-13 14:03:00.0
>   2012-12-28 11:03:00.0
>   2012-12-28 13:49:21.0

And after:

```
Collections.sort(retVal, new CommunicationsComparator());
```

> 2012-12-13 14:03:00.0
>   2012-12-06 15:03:01.0
>   2012-12-03 12:03:01.0
>   2012-11-28 11:28:11.0
>   2012-10-09 03:02:00.0
>   2012-10-08 13:02:02.0
>   2012-11-26 10:02:05.0
>   2012-10-07 03:02:01.0
>   2012-10-03 10:02:02.0
>   2012-12-28 13:49:21.0
>   2012-12-28 11:03:00.0

Any ideas why the bottom two objects might not be sorted correctly?  I am using the MySQL JDBC implementation of this Timestamp.

Comment: Why are you sorting on timestamp subtraction? More specifically, what is the spec where this is implemented?

Comment: `java.sql.Timestamp` implements `Comparable` and has thus a `compareTo()` method. Why not delegating directly to it like `return comm1.getDate().compareTo(comm2.getDate());`?

Comment: @BalusC That is the best approach and honestly I feel stupid for not thinking about it.  This is what I will do.

Comment: You're welcome. It look like that Peter has copied this answer afterwards, so I won't repost it.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

The difference between the last 2 dates and earlier dates will overflow integer.

Perhaps a better solution would be to compare the values, rather than subtract them.

```
    long t1 = comm1.getDate().getTime();
    long t2 = comm2.getDate().getTime();
    if(t2 > t1)
            return 1;
    else if(t1 > t2)
            return -1;
    else
            return 0;
```

Comment: Looks perfect and secure to me.

Comment: @MrSmith42 What a complete beginner mistake that I have made!  Thanks for pointing this out to me. :)

Comment: A short way of doing this using the ternary operator: `return t1 == t2 ? 0 : t1 < t2 ? -1 : 1;`

Comment: I wouldn't say a beginner's mistake  - but a very nice insight by op's replying knight.

Answer (score 6):

If the difference is bigger than about 25 days, an overflow occurs. (An int cannot represent a bigger time difference in milliseconds than about 25 days). This will make the comparison incorrect.

This can be solved by changing the return statement into:

```
return Long.signum(t2 - t1);
```

Comment: You still have an (admittedly unrealistic for this use case as both values are positive) overflow possibility. It is generally preferable to compare instead of subtracting...

Answer (score 6):

You can use

```
return Long.compare(t2, t1);
```

but you are better off comparing the dates.

```
return comm2.getDate().compareTo(comm1.getDate());
```

Answer (score 4):

My first idea is that the problem is an overflow.
`t1` and `t2` are `long`s. The different may not fit in an int.

I would check that.

If compare on second-level is good enough for you, you should try:

```
return (int) ((t2 - t1)/1000);
```

This does not guarantee that there will be no overflows.
I would at least add a test.

I think the best answer is not mine.
My favorite is:

```
    if(t2 > t1)
        return 1;
    else if(t1 > t2)
        return -1;
    else
        return 0;
```

Comment: Question is, does the difference also nt always fit in an `int`. It seams so.

Answer (score 0):

In java 8 and above we can Do this in a very clean and simple manner by:

```
list.stream().max(Comparator.comparing(YourCustomPojo::yourDateField))
```

This works with any Pojo having field type with support of `compareTo()`. `java.sql.Timeastamp` and `java.util.Date` comes with out of the box support for this method.

check the java doc [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Comparable.html#compareTo-T-)